# Cycle to get the source of a list of images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list with 8 thumbnails images. When I click in one of them the bigger image gets the source of the that thumbnail. I can do this one by one.

```
$('#img_1').click(function(){
    var temp = $('#img_1').attr('src');
    $('#bigger_image').attr('src', temp);
});
```

I tried to use a for loop but I always get the last thumbnail source

```
for(var i=0; i<$('#thumbsContainer').children().length;i++){
    $('#img_'+i).click(function(){
        var temp = $('#img_'+i).attr('src');
        $('#bigger_image').attr('src', temp);
    });
}
```

How should I do it in a once?

Comment: Do you mean Cycle or circle instead of cicle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for(var i=0; i<$('#thumbsContainer').children().length;i++){
    $('#img_'+i).click(function(){
        $('#bigger_image').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also loop over the images using the each function.

```
$('#thumbsContainer [id^=img_]').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $('bigger_image').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
    });
}
```